# Create the same div dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to reprodruce the same div content from a form but I wish to generate it dynamically.

As you can see on this http://jsfiddle.net/Tk7Pm/
This is the html part I want to reproduce.

```
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" id="qCB" checked="">  

    <div class="input-group col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="optionName[]" value="C" placeholder="Entrez un nom de choix...">
        <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="border:0;"></span>    
    </div>

 <input type="hidden" name="optionVal[]" value="1">
</div>
```

So As you can see in the jsfiddle link, i tried to create a div and a subdiv and append the subdiv in the first one but i had an empty subdiv.

Comment: Maybe you want : subdiv.appendTo(div); instead of subdiv.append(div); As I don't see anywhere that you are appending that subdiv to the dom tree..

Comment: Jsfiddle is not working well but I copied the output I have in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing the order in which you were calling your `appendTo` statements and converting from:

```
$('<input />',{type : 'checkbox',name:'checkBoxQuest[]',value:1,placeholder:"Votre choix..."}).appendTo(div);
```

to:

```
$('<input type="checkbox" name="checkBoxQuest[]" checked=""/>').appendTo(div);
```

style of providing the content to append I was able to have additional choices added. I didn't include the id="qCB" to the checkboxes so they aren't getting styled quite the same as those above.

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/Tk7Pm/4/